# How To Include "part#+.rar" In "Extensions

Tags: python, naming

So I'm using a script to split filenames into "name" and "extension" so I can then apply a bunch of rules to and play around with the "name" and have the script put everything back together at the end.

At the moment, I'm using:

```
import os, shutil, re
def rename_file (original_filename):
    name, extension = os.path.splitext(original_filename)    
    name = re.sub(r"\'", r"", name) # etc...more of these...
    new_filename = name + extension
    try:
        # moves files or directories (recursively)
        shutil.move(original_filename, new_filename)
    except shutil.Error:
        print ("Couldn't rename file %(original_filename)s!" % locals())
[rename_file(f) for f in os.listdir('.') if not f.startswith('.')]
```

My problem is that os.path.splitext() includes "the .part(s)" of the ".partX.rar" as part of the filename, whereas I'd like it to be included as part of the file extension.

How can I get the the script to do that (without having a list of "extensions" or a completely separate script for rar files)?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!  I'm sorry, I attempted to use the arrows to show appreaciation (but can't yet because I didn't have enough rep, which did seem pretty weird).  Thanks for bringing this to my attentions (my bad!)!  =D

Comment: This is how Stackoverflow works and it is rude not to accept answers... but I can see that you found the way to handle it. And furthermore, you have now the needed reputation to upvote :)

Comment: Yes, I just didn't understand that there was an "Acceptance" that was distinct from voting an answer up (I honestly thought I just couldn't do the non-rude thing yet).  Thanks again! =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.path.splitext` does a reverse search for '.' and returns the first match it finds.  So out of the box splitext will not do what you need.  If you are just using it to tokenize file names I suggest that you parse the filename yourself by splitting on . taking the left side as  the name and then rejoining the right side.

Here is one way to do it:

```
def split_name(file_name):
   '''
    Returns root_filename, 'middle tokens', and extension
   '''
   tokens = file_name.split('.')

   return (tokens[0], ".".join(tokens[1:-1]), tokens[-1]) if len(tokens) >1 else file_name
```

---

```
file_name = 'this.is.a.txt'
split_name(file_name)
#result is:
>>>  ('this', 'is.a', 'txt')
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm sorry, I attempted to use the arrows to show appreaciation (but can't yet because I didn't have enough rep, which did seem pretty weird).  Thanks for bringing this to my attentions (my bad!)!  =D

Comment: One of the big things I'm looking for the script to do and one of the reasons I can't have the ".part" included is that I'm looking to remove all the "."s from the name part (which messes everythging up for parts of rars).  So the name will probably (at first) contain a lot of "."s.

Comment: I'm sorry, I feel like the information is mostly here, but I can't quite adapt this to what I'm looking for.\n

Comment: I'm sorry, I feel like the information is mostly here, but I can't quite adapt this to what I'm looking for.

For a filename "This.File's.Name.Needs.To.Be.Changed.A.Lot.part001.rar" Your script would give me a truple, to pretty up the name I'd also end up dealing with the "...part001".  Just changing the numbers I can adapt it to grab the last two parts as the "extension', but I need some way to have it give me a duple, with the last being the last ".ext", unless it's a part[whatever number of numbers].rar, at which point it will put that last two (but still as a duple).

Comment: So you basically want the last two if the "part0001" exists ?

Comment: If part anything exists.  1-1,000,000,000 (with any number of zeros preceding the first digit).